# Facebook login secure?

Tags: c#, asp.net, facebook, handlers

I want to let people to log in with "Facebook login".
but, I wonder if it is secure enough, or I'm just doing it wrong.

What I'm getting back after a successful login is the user data, with the facebook_id, which I'm inserting to the DB passed by a JavaScript reuest to the server via handler since I'm using asp.net.

But, what I think that by a malicious use, one can change that data. and insert rubbish to the server, or even insert different facebook_id.

So I wonder if the "Facebook login" is secure enough to use, or that I'm doing it wrong.
I thought about other option to pass that client data to the server - by postback the server with a hidden runat=server textboxes but still, malicious use can change those textboxes. I've read here about the option to let the users add password to their Facebook username but it sounds a bit not user-friendly.

Am I right? is that a way to do it more secure? Is there any cookie that Facebook put on the client browser that I can read from the server? as though a lot of websites use this "Facebook login" there might be another way that I didnt think about...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pass the access token up to the server (or check for it from the cookie Facebook sets) and then have the server call [https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=...](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=me) and get the Facebook ID that way.  You can get the access_token by calling [FB.getLoginStatus](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.getLoginStatus/) from the javascript sdk.

Comment: what access token? im not getting that after a user login.

Answer (score 0):

You can use oauth to transfer this operation to server side.

Have a look at this blog post:

http://you.arenot.me/2010/09/28/facebooks-graph-api-and-asp-net/

Answer (score 0):

It is important to make an independent call from the server, especially if you are storing their facebook user id in a database or something. That way, you know whether or not it is valid.

First, after calling the **FB.init** function in the Facebook Javascript SDK, you want to get the user's access token and facebook user id via the Javascript SDK similar to this:

```
            FB.getLoginStatus(function (response)
            {
                if (response.status === 'connected')
                {
                    var token = response.authResponse.accessToken;
                    var facebookUserID = response.authResponse.userID;
                }
            });
```

Second, once you got a token and facebook user ID, you will want to pass those variables to your server. If you are using WCF or some other form of web service along with [JSON.NET](http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json-net.aspx), you could create a method such as this:

```
        [WebInvokeAttribute(BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest, RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
        [OperationContractAttribute]
        public Stream AuthenticateFacebook(string facebookUserId, string token)
        {
            var json = new WebClient().DownloadString(string.Format("https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token={0}", token));

            JObject parsedJson = JObject.Parse(json);

            //Ensure that there isn't a random Facebook server error
            if (parsedJson["error"] != null)
            {
                throw new FaultException("Error parsing Facebook token.");
            }

            //Ensure the facebook user ID passed in via the client matches the one received from the server.
            if (Convert.ToString(parsedJson["id"]) != facebookUserId)
            {
                throw new FaultException("Facebook login ids do not match. Something fishy is going on...");
            }

            //Now you know you have a valid facebook login id. Do your database stuff or whatever else here.


        }
```

You now have validated that the user is who they say they are.